# Excel formula: identifying highest weights

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I need some help with the following assignment:

Task:
In the product Weight tab, you can see each product is weighted with a value per customer. Please create a Product Code for each customer based on these weights from Highest to Lowest.

You only need to select the top 2 products and list these in order to create the code. If the customer is active in only one product, then you need to repeat the letter so we have a double letter code for each customer.

Examples:

- If Customer 1 has a weight of 0.37 for Product A, 0.45 for Product B and 0.18 for Product C, then the customer will be a Product Code – BA.
- If Customer 2 has a weight of 0.85 for Product A, 0.15 for Product B and zero for all other products, then the customer will be a Product Code – AB.
- If Customer 3 has a weight of 1 for Product D and zero for all other products, then the customer will be a Product Code – DD.
- If Customer 4 has zero weight for all products, they will have no product code and can be labeled as – Not Active

This is what the sheet looks like:

```
Customer    A      B      C      D
ETC024007   0.22   0      0.78   0
ETC024305   0      0      1      0
ETC024674   1      0      0      0
ETC024764   1      0      0      0
ETC024903   1      0      0      0
ETC025540   1      0      0      0
ETC026419   0      0      1      0
ETC026442   0      0      1      0
ETC031213   1      0      0      0
ETC032050   1      0      0      0
ETC032646   0      0      1      0
ETC042838   0.44   0.14   0      0.42
ETC050897   0.02   0.98   0      0
ETC051706   0.07   0      0.93   0
ETC051796   1      0      0      0
ETC053121   0.99   0.01   0      0
ETC053131   0      0      1      0
ETC053159   1      0      0      0
ETC053343   0.1    0      0.9    0
ETC053346   1      0      0      0
ETC053449   1      0      0      0
ETC053517   1      0      0      0
ETC053697   1      0      0      0
ETC053849   1      0      0      0
ETC053923   1      0      0      0
ETC053940   1      0      0      0
ETC054251   1      0      0      0
ETC054283   0.56   0      0.44   0
```

Comment: Questions should show your attempts and what went wrong.  This just sounds like you've reposted a homework question hoping someone would do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the formula I came up with:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$E$1,1,MATCH(LARGE(B2:E2,1),A2:E2,0))&INDEX($A$1:$E$1,1,MATCH(IF(LARGE(B2:E2,2)=0,LARGE(B2:E2,1),LARGE(B2:E2,2)),A2:E2,0))
```

I put your array of data on a worksheet starting at cell A1 and put this formula into cell F2 (with the header "Product Code") and filled down the rest of the column. It should give the results you're looking for.

Have fun!